# Создание функции для случайного числа в swift

Tags: swift, случайные-числа

Добрый день пытаюсь понять как работь со свифтом в playground'e нужна функция, структура или расширение для генерации случайных чисел. Нашел вот такую структуру

```
struct Math {
    private static var seeded = false

    static func randomFractional() -> CGFloat {

        if !Math.seeded {
            let time = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
            srand48(time)
            Math.seeded = true
        }

        return CGFloat(drand48())
    }
}

Math.randomFractional()
```

Мне же нужно например я в xcode  появление разных объектов в разных местах

Comment: а чем arc4random_uniform() не нравится?

Answer (score 1):

Используй стандартные`arc4random()` или  `arc4random_uniform()`. Любые вариации с рандомайзингом чисел с этими функциями осуществимы

Comment: ну все, хватит уже мои комменты выдавать за свои ответы

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил.

Comment: три раза не заметили :)